# fragments on the 7 inches tablet

Tags: android, android-fragments

Can I use android fragments with 2 columns layout on the 7 inches android tablet? It has got 800 x 480 resolution.
When I use it on my smartphone with resolution 480 x 800, it shows as one column layout.

Comment: I think you can use even 3 columns layout on 6 inches device with 1027x768 resolution. But can you show the layout?

Comment: I haven't got concrete layout. I start to develop android app with 2 column fragments - oriented vertically in ratio 30:70. I want to test it on the real device and I want to buy 7 inches tablet with the resolution 800x480 (Prestigio Multipad PMP3370B, Navon Platinum 7 or Emgeton Consul 3).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
Since the screen size of smartphone is small, the fragments are shown as a separate activity whereas in tablet it is shown in 2 column layout.
Moreover, it is not related to screen resolution
Refer this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: +1. Also, `res/layout/main.xml` for handsets and `res/layout-large/main.xml` for tablets.

Comment: So, I ran basic application - MasterDetail with two columns. I've run it on emulators with the resolution 800x480 and 1280x768. In the first case it ran as two activities, in the second case it ran properly.